# How do I make sure that all of the items that I read from a CSV are parsed into a dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a large CSV file from which I am reading some data and adding that data into a dictionary. My CSV file has approximately 360000 rows and my dictionary has only a length of 5700. I know my CSV has a lot of duplicates but I expect about 50000 unique rows. I know that Python dictionaries have no limits to size. My code reads all the 360000 entries in the file, writes it to another file and terminates. All this processing finishes in about 2 seconds without any exceptions. How do I know for sure that all of the items in the CSV that I process are actually being added to the dictionary?

The code that I am using is  as follows:

```
with open("read.csv", 'rb') as input1:
    with open("write.csv", 'wb') as output1:
        reader = csv.reader(input1, delimiter="\t")
        writer = csv.writer(output1, delimiter="\t")
        #Just testing if my program reads the whole CSV file
        for row in reader:
            count += 1
        print count        # Gives 360000
        input1.seek(0)
        for row in reader:
            #print row[1] + "\t" + row[2]
            dict1.update({row[1] : [ row[2], row[0] ]}) 
        print len(dict1)   # Gives 5700
        for key in dict1:
            ext_id = key
            list1 = dict1[key]
            name = list1[0]
            url = list1[1]
            writer.writerow([ext_id, name, url])
```

**EDIT**

I am not sure if people are understanding what I am trying to do and how that would be relevant but still, I'll explain.

My CSV file has 3 columns for each row. Their format is as follows:

```
URL+unique value | unique value | some name
```

However, the rows are duplicated in the CSV and I want another CSV which just has rows without any duplicates.

Comment: Please indent your code. Right now it is not valid Python.

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed the code.

Comment: @adsmith What do you mean by columns of a dictionary? A dictionary has a `len`, that's all.

Comment: @LutzHorn ah crap I misread his code. Why would anyone DO this...

Comment: @TheRookierLearner Maybe it would be helpful if you explained what you are trying to do.  As Lutz Horn's answer has pointed out, it doesn't matter if the rows are unique, only if the second item in the row is unique.

Comment: For each row[0] I have a unique row[1] and row[2]. So basically, it doesn't matter if I choose anyone of them.

Comment: @TheRookierLearner Maybe a dictionary is the wrong data type then, again, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For each _unique_ row in the `read.csv` I want to add the entry in `write.csv`. That's the reason I used dictionary in the first place.

Comment: @TheRookierLearner if you're just looking for uniqueness, try using a `set` instead? But I thought you said every `row[1]` and `row[2]` were unique?

Comment: I am using a dioctionary because I want to associate `row[1]` and `row[2]` with `row[0]`. I can't do that using a set.

Comment: If you want the *rows* to be unique you can't use a dictionary where only *one field* used as the key is considered for uniquness.

Comment: @TheRookierLearner why not? Frankly you're not even doing that now, you're associating `row[0]` and `row[2]` with `row[1]`! Read my updated answer.

Comment: @TheRookierLearner my answer does exactly what you specify you need to do. Read it, try it, weep before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: if you're just checking for uniqueness, there's no need to put this into a dictionary (which are designed for fast lookup and grouping). Use a `set` here instead.

```
out_ = set()

for row in reader:
    out_.add(tuple(row))
# csv.reader may iterate through tuples already, I don't know! If so
# there's obviously no reason to cast it as one. Do:
## print(type(reader[0]))
# to find out.

for row in out_:
    writer.writerow([row[1], row[0], row[2]])
```

Here's the quickest check I can think of.

```
set_headers = {row[1] for row in reader}
```

This is a set containing all the 2nd columns (that is to say, `row[1]`) of all the rows in your CSV. As you probably know, sets cannot contain duplicates, so this gives you how many UNIQUE values you have in your header column of each row.

Since `dict.update` REPLACES values, this is exactly what you're going to see with `len(dict1)`, in fact `len(set_headers) == len(dict1)`. Each time you iterate through a row, `dict.update` CHANGES THE VALUE of the key `row[1]` to `(row[0], row[2])`. Which is probably just fine if you don't care about the earlier values, but somehow I don't think that's true.

Instead, do this:

```
for row in reader:
    dict1.setdefault(row[1],[]).append((row[0],row[1]))
```

This will end up with something like:

```
dict1 = {"foo": [(row1_col0,row1_col2),(row3_col0,row3_col2)],
         "baz": [(row2_col0,row2_col2)]}
```

from input of:

```
row1_col0, foo, row1_col2
row2_col0, baz, row2_col2
row3_col0, foo, row3_col2
```

Now you can do, for instance:

```
for header in dict1:
    for row in header:
        print("{}\t{}".format(row[0],row[1]))
```

Comment: If you use `get` like that you won't accumulate the values, because it doesn't store the resulting list anywhere.  Were you thinking of `setdefault`?

Comment: @DSM thanks, I was! I'll edit. It looks like OP may be better served ignoring the dictionary though

Answer (score 3):

The keys in your dictionary are `row[1]`. The size of the dictionary will depend on how many different values of this field are in the input. It does not matter if the rest of the row (`row[2], row[0]`)  differs between rows.

Example:

```
a,foo,1
b,bar,2
c,foo,3
d,baz,4
```

Will result in a dictionary of length `3` if the first field (index `1`) is used as a key. The result will be:

```
{'foo':['3', 'c'],
 'bar':['2', 'b'],
 'baz':['4', 'd']}
```

The first line will be overwritten. Of course the 'order' can be different since a dictionary has no order.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to make sure you are getting everything is to add 2 test lists. Add: test1,test2=[],[], then right after you update your dictionary add test1.append(row[1]) then if row[1] not in test2: test2.append(row[1]). then you can print the length of both lists and see if the length of test2 is the same as your dictionary and the length of test1 is the same as the length of your input csv.

```
with open("read.csv", 'rb') as input1:
    with open("write.csv", 'wb') as output1:
        reader = csv.reader(input1, delimiter="\t")
        writer = csv.writer(output1, delimiter="\t")
        #Just testing if my program reads the whole CSV file
        test1,test2=[],[]
        for row in reader:
            count += 1
        print count        # Gives 360000
        input1.seek(0)
        for row in reader:
            #print row[1] + "\t" + row[2]
            dict1.update({row[1] : [ row[2], row[0] ]})
            test1.append(row[1])
            if row[1] not in test2: test2.append(row[1])
        print 'dictionary length:', len(dict1)   # Gives 5700
        print 'test 1 length (total values):',len(test1)
        print 'test2 length (unique key values):',len(test2)
        for key in dict1:
            ext_id = key
            list1 = dict1[key]
            name = list1[0]
            url = list1[1]
            writer.writerow([ext_id, name, url])
```

Comment: Please *indent* your code. This is not valid Python.